# org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

Tags: java, excel, apache, rest, apache-poi

I am trying to read a xlsx file using Apache POI, but its giving me below error:
org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

My Controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public ResponseEntity<SalesforceLoadUser> uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
           @NotNull @NotEmpty @RequestParam @DefaultValue(value = "false") final boolean testUser) throws IOException {

        final SalesforceLoadUser sfData = salesforecEventService.uploadUserFile(uploadedInputStream, testUser);

        final ResponseEntity<SalesforceLoadUser> finalResponse = new ResponseEntity<SalesforceLoadUser>(sfData, HttpStatus.OK);
        log.debug("Data load started for test user",testUser, finalResponse.getStatusCode());

        return finalResponse;

        //return uploadSFUserFile(uploadedInputStream,testUser);
    }
```

And my file reader is:

```
@Override
public SalesforceLoadUser uploadUserFile(InputStream openInputStream , boolean testUsers) throws IOException {

    final SalesforceLoadUser sfUserData = new SalesforceLoadUser();
    try {
        // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
        Workbook myWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(openInputStream);


        // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
        Sheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

     // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
      //  Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();

     // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
        int rowsCount = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("Total Number of Rows: " + (rowsCount + 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
            Row row = mySheet.getRow(i);
            int colCounts = row.getLastCellNum();
            System.out.println("Total Number of Cols: " + colCounts);
            for (int j = 0; j < colCounts; j++) {

            //final Optional<CommsPhysician> checkUserRecord = repo.findPhysicianByNPI(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

                sfUserData.setNPI(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

                sfUserData.setFirstName(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setLastName(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setGender(row.getCell(14).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setGradYear((int) row.getCell(16).getNumericCellValue());
                sfUserData.setClassification(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setEmail(row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setStatus(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setSpecialty(row.getCell(17).getStringCellValue());

                // Populate Roles
                if (row.getCell(6).getBooleanCellValue()) {
                    sfUserData.setJvp(row.getCell(6).getBooleanCellValue());
                }
                if (row.getCell(5).getBooleanCellValue()) {
                    sfUserData.setMd(row.getCell(5).getBooleanCellValue());

                }
                if (row.getCell(7).getBooleanCellValue()) {

                    sfUserData.setCredentialed(row.getCell(7).getBooleanCellValue());
                }

                // Populate Address
                sfUserData.setStreet(row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setCity(row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setState(row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue());

                // Populate Palmer and Division
                sfUserData.setPalmer(row.getCell(12).getStringCellValue());
                sfUserData.setDivision(row.getCell(13).getStringCellValue());

                // Set boolean for test user from request
                sfUserData.setTestUser(testUsers);

                salesforceBrokerService.publishToBroker(sfUserData);


            }
        }

       //Close the workbook
        myWorkBook.close();

    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (openInputStream != null){
            //Close the excel input file (inputstream)  
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(openInputStream);
        }
    }

    return sfUserData;
}
```

its throwing error when Workbook is trying to create inputStream.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here. My xlsx file is neither corrupt nor empty.

Comment: Although I could imagine, that we have a problem reading from a blocking stream, I would first try (as a test) to store that InputStream to a local file. If this looks good, you might need to buffer that InputStream with a ByteArrayOutput/InputStream and process that instead.